# I want my PCwin10 to wakeup by moving my wireless mouse

Tags: mouse, wake-up, logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse, wake-on-demand

Wake up via mouse does not work. I have my Windows 10 set to `hybrid sleep` and `USB selective suspend` enabled.

Comment: Try turning Hybrid Sleep OFF and use regular Suspend. Then it may depend on the mouse. Mice with the RF USB device are more likely to wake up the computer than a Bluetooth mouse.

Comment: That alone does not help. I have a Logitech MX Anywhere 2 with a unified receiver.

Comment: I am not sure. Most (may I say all) my clients do not want moving the mouse to wake up their laptop as that may happen in their bag causing the laptop to overheat

Comment: Well this is a fast HTPC I want to use way less electricity, so getting up to turn it on all the time is an annoyance.

Comment: Is the mouse and unified receiver set in device manager to allow it to wake PC from sleep?

Comment: You might also update the the unified firmware>>>>https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360033207154-Logitech-Unifying-Receiver-Update

Comment: Firmware update crashed, saying "can't find the intel craphics". I have two uninstalled devices in device manager. Other is `Unknown device`, other is `USB receiver`. I cannot install `SetPoint`, it just "failed to install". Maybe I should try reinstalling Windows fresh..

Comment: Driver Fusion was able to update my driver. Still does not wake up my computer though.

Answer (score 0):

That actually depends on the wireless mouse you have more than the software side, some mice will not work unless you actually click on a button, just moving will not work as it will keep the optical sensor off to save power and it may not have a gyro sensor to detect movement, so the only way to make the mouse *wake* from a low-power state is to click any button.

Comment: Wake up by clicking the mouse also would work for me, but it does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

You might check this setting in the device properties...

[image: HID-compliant mouse Properties]

Comment: I have that option enabled, does not work